# How can I convert a whole column of formulas into a new column of slightly modified versions of the same formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

The Excel file in question has the 58 California counties in Column A, the measure "Col 1" in Column B. Column B cites data from another Excel file, so the column contains formulas that look something like this:

```
='[CA 237 Time Series.xlsx]ALPINE'!$BM$26

='[CA 237 Time Series.xlsx]CALAVERAS'!$BM$26

='[CA 237 Time Series.xlsx]LOS ANGELES'!$BM$26
```

[Excel worksheet in question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3OyC.png)

And so on. It looks like this for all 58 rows in column B.

Now here's the problem. I'd like to convert these formulas such that they refer to column A of the cited worksheet [CA 237 Time Series], and paste that in Column C. This is because column A in the [CA 237 Time Series] refers to date column, which is something I need to check. All the items in column B of the current file (NOT CA 237 Time Series) should be converted to:

```
='[CA 237 Time Series.xlsx]ALPINE'!$A$26

='[CA 237 Time Series.xlsx]CALAVERAS'!$A$26

='[CA 237 Time Series.xlsx]LOS ANGELES'!$A$26
```

and then pasted into Column C.

And to that end, I discovered the SUBSTITUTE formula. I can do something like this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(B2), "BM", "A")
```

And the result converts the formula to:

```
='[CA 237 Time Series.xlsx]ALPINE'!$A$26
```

[But it seems to return the results to me as a STRING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xMYd.png). That is, the SUBSTITUTE function literally returns "='[CA 237 Time Series.xlsx]ALPINE'!$A$26" as a string without evaluating it. I do not know how to make it evaluate the new formula. How can I convert the formula into a modified version of the same formula and evaluate it?

[In the end, the Excel file should look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r0la.png) After altering the formulas in column B and putting it in column C, it should evaluate it and return a date (in this case, July 2022).

Comment: Hi, What might help people give you the suggestions you are looking for is an example.  This is what I have in this is what I'm looking to get. Basically before and after.

Comment: Is this a one-time or a recurring task?

Comment: use `INDIRECT()`

Comment: @BradR Sorry about that. I've updated it with images to be more clear.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad This is a one-time task.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a number of ways, but a simple `Find and Replace` is the easiest.

In this case, search for the string `$CE$` and replace it with the string `$A$`.

Excel will do the replacements and keep the formulas as formulas.

This method is much harder when it is not so easy to isolate the string that needs replacement. It is impossible to do the simple version that works here when there are, say, two elements needing replacement and the first leaves a formula with structural errors in it. But if you ever have one of those, ask because it's still conceptually easy, no matter how many steps.

A different way would be to obtain the text strings you get from your described method and then look for a common element. If there is one, you can do the whole range at once. If not, then one by one or subsets, though that could be painful.

In your case the `[` character, or better, the pair of `'[` leaps out at one. Since there IS a useful search string, copy the range and `Paste|Special|Values` to convert to strings, not `FORMULATEXT` results. (While one can `Find` using cell results instead of their formulas, one cannot find and replace. Not in my version.) Finally, use the find and replace feature to find that string... and replace it with itself. So one find and replace for the whole range of cells.

Excel immediately converts your string to an actual formula. Even if the cell was (and still is) formatted as Text, the formula will work and you will see the result instead of the string. It is certainly odd to see a numerical result justified at the left edge with Text as the format and General for the alignment, but this a way to see just that.

One can even use VBA's Immediate Window to do the conversion, but the above ways are more congenial to the random user. (Make sure the cell formats in the range are NOT Text, then with the range selected type or paste `selection.value = selection.value` into the Immediate Window and press Enter.)

Answer (score 0):

As @gns100 said in a comment, use INDIRECT(), in combination with the SUBSTITUTE you had already found. So something like `=INDIRECT(=SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(B2), "BM", "A"))`